# Dereferencing void * pointer, array of structs

Tags: c

I am trying to change a void * pointer into an array of structs.
The point is to have a global visible pointer initialized to NULL, that when main starts, will be turned to an array of structs
 Here is a minimal example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void * hashtable;

struct bucket {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main (void)
{
    hashtable = (struct bucket)malloc(6*sizeof(struct bucket));
    int i ;
    //for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    //  hashtable[i] =  malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));

    *(struct bucket)hashtable[0]->a = 12;

    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
test.c:16:52: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
  hashtable = (struct bucket)malloc(6*sizeof(struct bucket));
                                                ^
test.c:21:27: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
  *(struct bucket)hashtable[0]->a = 12;
                       ^
test.c:21:27: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Comment: `*(struct bucket)hashtable[0]->a = 12;` ==> `((struct bucket*)hashtable)->a = 12;`

Comment: why carrying struct around? use a typedef.

Comment: Well that helped a bit. but now I get "test.c:16:52: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
  hashtable = (struct bucket)malloc(6*sizeof(struct bucket));"

Comment: Better to use `struct bucket * hashtable;` after the `struct` definition.  "trying to change a void * pointer into an array of structs."  Why do you want a `void *`?

Comment: `hashtable = malloc(6*sizeof(struct bucket));`

Comment: Tip: Stop casting the result of `malloc()`.  It is not needed  and code is doing it wrong anyways.

Comment: Many thanks guys for your immediate help!!

Comment: Any reason you're not declaring `hashtable` as a `struct bucket *`?

Comment: You need to read a bit about the pointers.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned already, you shouldn't be casting the result of `malloc()` here:

```
hashtable = (struct bucket)malloc(6*sizeof(struct bucket));
```

Trim it down to:

```
hashtable = malloc(6*sizeof(struct bucket));
```

---

As for your assignment:

```
*(struct bucket)hashtable[0]->a = 12;
```

1. Your program first tries to compute `hashtable[0]->a`, but that gives you that compiler warning since you haven't cast `hashtable` yet (`[]` and `->` have higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than casting).
2. You need to cast to `struct bucket *` since `hashtable` is a pointer.
3. You attempt to dereference `hashtable` too many times; you don't need the extra `*` and `->` operators.

With this in mind, you can access `a` of `hashtable`'s first element as follows:

```
((struct bucket *)hashtable)[0].a = 12;
```

Of course, you might have an easier time defining `struct bucket * hashtable;` to avoid casting `hashtable` every time you want to work it.